# HANA cloud integration HTTP PATCH operation

Tags: groovy, integration, hana, sap-business-technology-platform

How can I use HTTP Patch operation in SAP HANA Cloud integration?

I can only see below 4 operations in Http adapter in HCI.

1. PUT
2. GET
3. POST
4. DELETE.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to decide between MERGE and CREATE. There is no patch, but as far as I know, sending a PUT as batch + using/redefining "PATCH_ENTITY" in backend results in exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Dynamic method:
[image: figure]

CamelHttpMethod is common header for HTTPS adapter.